# Where clause using Expression <Func<>> and <T>

Tags: c#, .net, linq, generics

Here this is my code:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public Place place {get; set;}
}

public class Customer : Person
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string CustomerProperty {get; set;}
}

public class Employee : Person
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string EmployeeProperty {get; set;}
}
```

So I created a method to use linq Where clause to filter by estate or city or place.

```
        public static Expression<Func<Customer, bool>> FilterByPlace(string stateId, string cityId, string placeId)
    {
        if (placeId != null)
        {
            return u => u.PlaceId == placeId;
        }
        else if (cityId != null)
        {
            return u => u.Place.Address.cod_city == cityId;
        }
        else if (stateId != null)
        {
            return u => u.Place.Address.City.cod_state == stateId;
        }

        return u => true;
    }
```

If I want to do this for Employees I need to duplicate and change this `<Func<Customer>>` to `<Func<Employee>>`. Is there a way to use `<T>` in instead of my entity?

When I change the code for `<Func<Person>>` it returns error because the Type is different of the expected on linq expression.

```
var custom = db.Customers
                            .Include(item => item.Place)
                            .Include(item => item.Place.Address)
                            .Include(item => item.Place.Address.City)
                            .Include(item => item.Place.Address.City.State)
                            .Where(item => item.Status == (Status)tableStatus)
                            .Where(FilterByPlace(stateId, cityId, placeId))
                            .OrderByDescending(item => item.CustomerId);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try making a generic method with `Person` as the generic constraint.

```
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> FilterByPlace<T>(string stateId, string cityId, string placeId) 
   where T : Person
{
    if (placeId != null)
    {
        return u => u.PlaceId == placeId;
    }
    else if (cityId != null)
    {
        return u => u.Place.Address.cod_city == cityId;
    }
    else if (stateId != null)
    {
        return u => u.Place.Address.City.cod_state == stateId;
    }

    return u => true;
}
```

Comment: The query is returning error

Error 1 'System.Linq.IQueryable<TrulyNolen.DAL.Entities.Customer>' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Queryable.Where<TSource>(System.Linq.IQueryable<TSource>, 
System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TSource,int,bool>>)' has some invalid arguments
Error 2 Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<T,bool>>' to 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TrulyNolen.DAL.Entities.Customer,int,bool>>'

Comment: Error 3 The type arguments for method 'FilterByPlace<T>(string, string, string)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: _Try specifying the type arguments explicitly._ means to call it like `FilterByPlace<Customer>`

Comment: Awesome! I didn't know the use of 'where' like you posted, it works fine.